# Setting an Outlook category programmatically via Office JS API

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

Does anyone know how to read/write categories of an Outlook item via JavaScript API for Office?
It seems there is no information connected with Categories in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's part of the JavaScript API directly yet; with enough permissions you should be able to use [mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp161019.aspx) to make [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa565683(v=exchg.150).aspx) calls (with XML) to get/set the categories.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use is to have your web application call the [Office 365 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage) and update the category of the Outlook item.